# Applying CanvasTexture as a map to an imported .obj model

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js

I have a .obj file that I am importing like so:

```
OBJLoader.load('/models/model.obj', m => {
                    let model = m.children[0];
                    model.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();
                    scene.add(model);
                });
```

I override the default material with a THREE.MeshBasicMaterial so I can edit the map separately.

Later on, I am getting a CanvasTexture and using it as the map:

```
let texture = new CanvasTexture(canvas);
model.material.map = texture;
model.material.needsUpdate = true;
```

This seems to work, but I cannot see the texture properly on the object in the scene - it looks like it is very 'zoomed' - only showing the overall color of the texture, not any detail. I have played around with `texture.repeat`, but can't seem to get what I want, which is:

The texture should appear on the object and scale to fill the object. I made the object in Blender, and it has many faces, but I want the texture to fill the entire object across all faces, without repeats.

How can I achieve this?

Edit: Here is the model I'm using https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1y6NmxNpamCtWsiBPlDhndnvQbxYPVgB7?usp=sharing

Comment: Any chances to share the model in this thread?

Comment: @Mugen87 Edited with a link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `OBJ` file does not contain any texture coordinates. Hence it's not possible to apply a texture in the way you are looking for.

Since you are working with Blender, it should be straightforward to author suitable texture coordinates. Besides, I highly recommend you export your model to the more modern `glTF` format instead of `OBJ`. `glTF` is the recommended 3D format of `three.js`.

Comment: Thanks @Mugen87. I added texture coords and that didn't seem to help. I'm new to Blender so I may have done it wrong. I have updated the drive link above with the .blend file - I don't suppose you could confirm if that's ok?

Comment: I can't see any uv data in your blend file. I suggest you click on your model, go to `UV Editing`, go into `Edit Mode` (press Tab), select the entire vertex data and then use `UV` (press U) and then use `Unwrap`.

Comment: Having done that, I am now getting a plain black object. I have added an image to the blend shading to demo what I'm adding in the three scene - this image will be dynamic which is why I'm adding it as a canvas texture

Comment: Fixed the problem with the above - changing the roughness/metalness of the material got it right.